# maven archetype property substitution

Tags: maven-3, maven-archetype

Anybody knows is it possible to make substitution for default value of one `requredProperty` to another in archetype-metadata.xml ?

So, I try to do something like this:

```
<requiredProperty key="name"/>
<requiredProperty key="groupId">
   <defaultValue>com.mycompamy.${name}</defaultValue>
</requiredProperty>
```

But when I start to generate project from artifact in interactive mode, maven asks me about `groupId` property first. But not for `name` as I expected.

Is it possible to change this behaviour?

Answer (score 13):

Your problem is caused by `required property` loading order. Maven loads every custom `required property` in alphabetical order. You probably cant change it. But there are 2 ways which will solve your problem:

1. Renaming ur variables like this:

   `"0_name"`

   `"1_groupId"`

   Now it will ask you about name firstly.
2. Use full maven command, passing only name parameter

   `mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=?? -DarchetypeArtifactId=?? -DgroupId=?? -DartifactId=?? -Dversion=?? -Dpackage=?? -Dname=??`

   Replace `??` with valid parameters

Hope it will helps you.

EDIT: now i see an `asked time`. Pretty offtopic but maybe it will help someone else