# Is there a way to order properties in a maven archetype?

Tags: maven-3, maven-archetype

I created a maven archetype. In the `archetype-metadata.xml` I have a section similar to this one:

```
<requiredProperties>
    <requiredProperty key="projectName"/>
    <requiredProperty key="projectDescription"/>
</requiredProperties>
```

But when I try to create a project based on this archetype in interactive mode, maven first asks the user for `projectDescription` and then for `projectName`. I would like to reverse this so that user is first asked for `projectName` and then for `projectDescription`. I can do this by renaming property keys to, say, `01projectName` and `02projectDescription` but this looks quite ugly. So, is there any way to define in which order would maven ask for properties when creating a new project?

Comment: This question was [already asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13745247/maven-archetype-property-substitution), but the answer there only contains workarounds you already know. I'll leave it for you to decide whether it's a duplicate or not. There is also [a related bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARCHETYPE-443) in Maven issue tracker that was auto-closed due to inactivity (you might as well try to reopen it).

Comment: @defaultlocale Thanks for the comment, I'd say it is a duplicate. The answer to the previous question contains a lot of information about this problem.